# I have been trying to convert a TensorFlow code to pytorch and main problem is ,what to use in place tf.keras.layers.Layer in pytorch

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow2.0, tensor, pytorch-forecasting

I have been trying to convert the TensorFlow code into pytorch ,facing the problem ,what to use tf.keras.layer.Layer in pytorch ,Here below is the code ,could any pls help me out with this part?

```py
"""
Objective wrapper and utils to build a function to be optimized
"""

import itertools

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from ..commons import find_layer
from ..types import Union, List, Callable, Tuple, Optional
from .losses import dot_cossim


class Objective:
    """
    Use to combine several sub-objectives into one.

    Each sub-objective act on a layer, possibly on a neuron or a channel (in
    that case we apply a mask on the layer values), or even multiple neurons (in
    that case we have multiples masks). When two sub-objectives are added, we
    optimize all their combinations.

    e.g Objective 1 target the neurons 1 to 10 of the logits l1,...,l10
        Objective 2 target a direction on the first layer d1
        Objective 3 target each of the 5 channels on another layer c1,...,c5

        The resulting Objective will have 10*5*1 combinations. The first input
        will optimize l1+d1+c1 and the last one l10+d1+c5.

    Parameters
    ----------
    model
        Model used for optimization.
    layers
        A list of the layers output for each sub-objectives.
    masks
        A list of masks that will be applied on the targeted layer for each
        sub-objectives.
    funcs
        A list of loss functions for each sub-objectives.
    multipliers
        A list of multiplication factor for each sub-objectives
    names
        A list of name for each sub-objectives
    """

    def __init__(self,
                 model: tf.keras.Model,
                 layers: List[tf.keras.layers.Layer],
                 masks: List[tf.Tensor],
                 funcs: List[Callable],
                 multipliers: List[float],
                 names: List[str]):
        self.model = model
        self.layers = layers
        self.masks = masks
        self.funcs = funcs
        self.multipliers = multipliers
        self.names = names

    def __add__(self, term):
        if not isinstance(term, Objective):
            raise ValueError(f"{term} is not an objective.")
        return Objective(
                self.model,
                layers=self.layers + term.layers,
                masks=self.masks + term.masks,
                funcs=self.funcs + term.funcs,
                multipliers=self.multipliers + term.multipliers,
                names=self.names + term.names
        )

    def __sub__(self, term):
        if not isinstance(term, Objective):
            raise ValueError(f"{term} is not an objective.")
        term.multipliers = [-1.0 * m for m in term.multipliers]
        return self + term

    def __mul__(self, factor: float):
        if not isinstance(factor, (int, float)):
            raise ValueError(f"{factor} is not a number.")
        self.multipliers = [m * factor for m in self.multipliers]
        return self

    def __rmul__(self, factor: float):
        return self * factor

    def compile(self) -> Tuple[tf.keras.Model, Callable, List[str], Tuple]:
        """
        Compile all the sub-objectives into one and return the objects
        for the optimisation process.

        Returns
        -------
        model_reconfigured
            Model with the outputs needed for the optimization.
        objective_function
            Function to call that compute the loss for the objectives.
        names
            Names of each objectives.
        input_shape
            Shape of the input, one sample for each optimization.
        """
        # the number of inputs will be the number of combinations possible
        # of the objectives, the mask are used to take into account
        # these combinations
        nb_sub_objectives = len(self.multipliers)

        # re-arrange to match the different objectives with the model outputs
        masks = np.array([np.array(m, dtype=object) for m in itertools.product(*self.masks)])
        masks = [tf.cast(tf.stack(list(masks[:, i])), tf.float32) for i in
                 range(nb_sub_objectives)]

        # the name of each combination is the concatenation of each objectives
        names = np.array([' & '.join(names) for names in
                           itertools.product(*self.names)])
        # one multiplier by sub-objective
        multipliers = tf.constant(self.multipliers)

        def objective_function(model_outputs):
            loss = 0.0
            for output_index in range(0, nb_sub_objectives):
                outputs = model_outputs[output_index]
                loss += self.funcs[output_index](
                    outputs, tf.cast(masks[output_index], outputs.dtype))
                loss *= multipliers[output_index]
            return loss

        # the model outputs will be composed of the layers needed
        model_reconfigured = tf.keras.Model(self.model.input, [*self.layers])

        nb_combinations = masks[0].shape[0]
        input_shape = (nb_combinations, *model_reconfigured.input.shape[1:])

        return model_reconfigured, objective_function, names, input_shape
```

I have tried to convert the code torch and expecting the same out as TensorFlow code

Comment: Please add more details to your problem, what errors (and where) do you encounter? PyTorch layers use [`Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html) as base class.

Comment: Keras 3 lets you just change the backend to pytorch. "I have tried to convert the code torch and expecting the same out as TensorFlow code" Are you getting output?

Comment: Iam just confused what to use in layer place ?

tf.keras.layers.Layer ,what to inherit in place torch usage